# installing ruby on rails without an internet connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation

I am trying to install ruby on rails in my own intranet,  I don't have an internet connection. There are several tutorials out there that try to explain how to do so, but they don't seem to work. Does anyone know of a full installation (including ruby, rails, IDE) that doesn't demand downloading files from the internet?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Download [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/downloads/) Ruby edition, and install on the machine of choice. It has JRuby bundled along with rails 2.3.5.